# MBProgressHUD curtain?

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

Is there a way to present a `MBProgressHUD` with a curtain obscuring the entire screen like `UIAlertController`?

This is what UIAlertController looks like:

[image: UIAlertController]

On the other hand, this is MBProgressHUD:

[image: MBProgressHUD]

I don't like this because it's not obvious to me that you need to wait on this.

I'd like something more like this:

[image: Wanted]

Note I'm not fussy about this appearance. I got this just by adjusting the brightness of the image. I'd be even happier if the HUD itself was lighter than the background, much like the alert over its background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JGProgressHUD [JGProgressHud](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGProgressHUD), this hud have several customizations that can fit your needs.